# Using GPU rendering on old AMD GPU

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, gpu

My system config are as follows:
Processor: i386
GPU: AMD Cedar (Mobility Radeon card 5k series) on a laptop
Blender Ver.: 2.79
OS: Windows XP 32bit( has Blender 2.76)/ Xubuntu 17.10 (blender installed on both)

Problem: I found out that GPU rendering is not working on my laptop. The option does not show in the device section in user preferences. I tried using the debug-flag thingy but even that doesn't show changes. Is there no way to use my GPU to render in Cycles rendering engine? And that too on any of the two OSes mentioned?

Comment: Imho absolutely not... way, way, way too old... i386???

Comment: Okay and not even using some other renderer? Lux?

Comment: Idk about lux... You could try some online rendering, if you have no other choice...

Comment: are you sure, there's not a typo in your hardware specs?

Comment: Nope. cycles will simply not render on a card that old.